# Error while running code in device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I am getting service invalid message when I run my iPhone application on the device. My device is properly added in provisioning profile & sometimes it works fine. But, now I am consistently getting this error. Please see the attached screenshot of the error. Any clue?

My XCODE version is 4.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you must reset the device